# Highest Status per ID per category

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with an problem to make a query of the following:

I have an table called Article_Statuses (and the main table Articles, with ArticleID as p.key) and has the following structure

```
ID, ArticleID, Status, Status_Date, Category
```

In this table I collect all the statuses of the articles (ArticleID) per category (which are predefined), the highest ID per category is the latest status of that category, herewith some data:

```
1, BB0001, LFS, 15-01-2015, LIC
2, BB0001, LFA, 19-01-2015, LIC
3, BB0001, SA, 10-01-2015, FIS
4, BB0001, CA, 19-01-2015, FIS
5, BB0002, LFS, 10-01-2015, LIC
6, BB0002, LFA, 11-01-2015, LIC
7, BB0003, CA, 19-01-2015, FIS
```

I want to make a query with the following result:

```
ArticleID, Status LIC, Status_Date LIC, Status FIS, Status_Date FIS
BB0001, LFA, 19-01-2015, CA, 19-01-2015
BB0002, LFA, 11-01-2015, ,
BB0003, , , CA, 19-01-2015
```

I found the following solution which works for only one category, I'm stuck with adding the other categories...

```
SELECT `a`.`ArticleID`, `b`.`Status_Date` AS `LIC_Date`, `b`.`Status` AS `LIC_Status`
FROM `Articles` `a` 
    INNER JOIN `Article_Statuses` `b` ON `a`.`ArticleID` = `b`.`ArticleID`
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT `ArticleID`, MAX( `ID` ) `MAXID`
    FROM `Article_Statuses`
    WHERE `Category` = 'LIC' GROUP BY `ArticleID` ) `c`
    ON `b`.`ArticleID` = `c`.`ArticleID` AND `b`.`ID` = `c`.`MAXID`
WHERE `a`.`Partner` = 10
GROUP BY `a`.`ArticleID` 
ORDER BY `a`.`ArticleID` ASC
```

Comment: Why the second group by?

Comment: Indeed not neccessary

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the meaning of "Partner" in your query? You didn't mentioned it anywhere earlier so I'm guessing it's not important.

How many different categories do you have? Just two or more? I'm asking because returning data in such a way is far for being fast and optimal.

It would be something like:

```
SELECT 
  a.ArticleID, 
  b.Status_Date AS LIC_Date, b.Status AS LIC_Status,
  d.Status_Date AS FIS_Date, d.Status AS FIS_Status
FROM Articles AS a 
    INNER JOIN Article_Statuses AS b ON a.ArticleID = b.ArticleID
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT ArticleID, MAX( ID ) AS ID
        FROM Article_Statuses
        WHERE Category = 'LIC' GROUP BY ArticleID
    ) AS c ON b.ArticleID = c.ArticleID AND b.ID = c.ID

    INNER JOIN Article_Statuses AS d ON a.ArticleID = d.ArticleID
    INNER JOIN ( 
        SELECT ArticleID, MAX( ID ) AS ID
        FROM Article_Statuses
        WHERE Category = 'FIS' GROUP BY ArticleID
    ) AS e ON d.ArticleID = e.ArticleID AND d.ID = e.ID

WHERE a.Partner = 10
ORDER BY a.ArticleID ASC
```

Basically you repeat joins just with different aliased - I used "d" and "e" but it's better to use something meaningful like "LIC_category" instead of just "b".

You also should use **left join** instead of inner join if some categories can be empty as in your example.

Comment: Do you really need it to have it all in one row? Then you just have to add another 2 joins for each category  but it will be really far from optimal. It would be much better in my opinion to get 8 rows for article and process it somewhere in code before displaying it.

Comment: Did my solution work or have you ended up making this some other way?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query which returns desired result:

```
select a.articleid, 
       b.status_date as LIC_Date, b.status as LIC_Status, 
       c.status_date as FIS_Date, c.status as FIS_Status  
from Articles a
left join Article_Statuses b on b.ArticleID =a.articleid and 
     b.id = (select max(id) from Article_Statuses ast 
             where ast.articleid=a.articleid and ast.category='LIC')
left join Article_Statuses c on c.ArticleID =a.articleid and 
    c.id = (select max(id) from Article_Statuses ast 
             where ast.articleid=c.articleid and ast.category='FIS')
order by a.articleid
```

I used left joins because not for every article both categories are present.